# Compass and straight edge

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Is there any method how to grab into compass, by using just compass and straight edge, side length of a cube, which is inside a given sphere, touching this sphere by corners, but this sphere is given by radius(diameter) as a circle in 2D plane ... sorry for my English, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to circumscribe a cube with sphere using only a compass and straight edge?

Comment: no , i am asking ,... imagine a given sphere , this sphere is yes circumscribed around the cube ,,, can we somehow get into the  compass the length of side of this cube  , by knowing the radius of that sphere ..so basically what we can do first in 2D plane is only circle .

Comment: Have you tried working out the lengths with the Pythagorean theorem?

Answer (score 1):

(Unlabeled) image constructed [here](https://sciencevsmagic.net/geo/#0A1.1A0.1L0.0L4.4L3.4A0.1L6.1L5.5L3.1L3.N.4L11).

[image]

The sphere is centred at $O$. Assume $OA=1$. The inner diagonal of the cube is the diameter of the sphere so has length $2$ and the side of the cube has length $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}$.

Triangle $ABC$ is right-angled at $C$. $AB=2$, $BC=1$, hence $AC=\sqrt{3}$.

Lines $BD$ and $EC$ are parallel and are part of a construction of the trisection of $AC$.

Hence, $AF$ = $\frac{2}{3}AC=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}$ as required.

Comment: Thank you "nickgard"  ,very very nice  ... i just figured out as well , but a bit different  ..construct one side of circumscribed hexagon , and this side is the same as AF